# Left-align Safari Favorites labels

Tags: safari, ui

Is there a hack to make the items in Safari's Favorites bar be left-aligned rather than centered?

I've never gotten used to having to scan visually for the folder I want.

Comment: A screenshot might help us know which version and platform you use with safari.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Safari 13.1.1 in Catalina 10.15.5 and all of sudden my folder items in Favorites bar became center-aligned from left-aligned. My Favorites in Safari had never been realigned since Tiger (OSX 10.4 in 2004)! All I did was to add a new folder item which got added to the left and after moving it to the right of other items, the Favorites became center-aligned. I cannot restore to original behavior and it's frustrating when I had to move my cursor further to the right on the folder items than where they used to be! If only I get access to HTML, XML, Java code for the Favorites bar, I can change the alignment! Someone did a workaround by creating one or more folders on the right with name ".        ." (blank chars with leading and trailing periods) to shift the alignment of other folder items to the left. But this doesn't work well when changing the screen size.